# How to print new row in word document using word temp-let

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-word

I am trying to add new row. But i am getting error like : There is no row position at 3.

```
          If OperCnt <> 0 Then

                   If myxmlnode.BaseName = "Oper" Then
                      If I < OperCnt Then
                         myxmlnode.Range.Text = DsOper.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("operationseq").ToString
                        setuptime = setuptime + DsOper.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("setup")
                        runtime = runtime + DsOper.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("runtime")
                        OperQty = CType(myDB.RetrieveData("select isnull(SUM(TRXQUANTITY),0) AS TRXQTY from sbm_laboractivity where wo_guid = '" & DsOper.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("wo_guid") & "' and operationseq = '" & DsOper.Tables(0).Rows(I).Item("operationseq") & "'"), Double)
                    End If
                    If I = OperCnt - 1 Then myxmlnode.Range.Select() : I = I + 1 : GoTo ee
                    myxmlnode.Range.Select()
                    Travelerdoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertRowsBelow()
                    I = I + 1


Here i am trying to add new row

               If myxmlnode.BaseName = "WC" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text =" "
               If myxmlnode.BaseName = "Desc" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text = DsOper.Tables(0).Rows(I - 1).Item("OPS_Note").ToString
              If myxmlnode.BaseName = "LC" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text = ""
              If myxmlnode.BaseName = "Setup" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text = ""
              If myxmlnode.BaseName = "RunTime" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text = ""
              If myxmlnode.BaseName = "Qty" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text = ""
              If myxmlnode.BaseName = "CompQty" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text = ""
              If myxmlnode.BaseName = "RemQty" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text = ""
              If myxmlnode.BaseName = "TotalSetup" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text = ""
              If myxmlnode.BaseName = "TotalRunTime" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text = ""
        End If
      End If
```

Can you give any suggestions for this.